# presentModalViewController for UIView

Tags: ipad, presentmodalviewcontroller

My class is a subclass of an UIView because I want to draw somthing.

Is it possible to use a ModalViewController in this Context?

I tried this:

```
DrawViewController *dc = [[DrawViewController alloc]init];

[dc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];

 [self presentModalViewController:dc animated:YES];
```

but it throws errors...

Answer (score 0):

No, only UIViewControllers can present modal view controllers, not UIViews.